# Is it possible to list two developers on the Apple App store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I developed an app on the Apple app store with a friend. We each have individual Apple developer accounts. We are not really a startup/business so we don't have an organization account.

Is it possible to list both names in the App store? Currently it only shows one name - the one that submitted the app. Is there somewhere to add another name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible. That's exactly why there is the enterprise account, so you can have teams and upload apps as a company.

However, it is possible to transfer the app from one account to another, but never two accounts at the same time.

Comment: Welp... But in order to get a developer account as a organization, we need to have "Legal entity status", according to here: https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/. So is there no way to co-develop an app without becoming a company?

Comment: That is correct, so in your case, according to that, there is no way to display both names.

Comment: The result is disappointing, but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

No, only the original poster will be shown.